# Edit HA cluster config cib.xml

Tags: linux, failovercluster, pacemaker, corosync

I want to edit pingd of my cluster config living on centos 6.5 because the addresses are no longer valid and my cluster always switching to the other node because of the failed nodes.What is the best way to do it.I know i must never open directly the cib.xml file.

```
[root@PBX1 mojo]# pcs config
Cluster Name: pbx
Corosync Nodes:
 pbx1 pbx2
Pacemaker Nodes:
 pbx1 pbx2

Resources:
 Master: master_drbd
  Meta Attrs: master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1 notify=true
  Resource: drbd_drbd0 (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
   Attributes: drbd_resource=drbd0
   Operations: monitor interval=10s (drbd_drbd0-monitor-interval-10s)
 Clone: Connectivity
  Resource: p_ping (class=ocf provider=pacemaker type=ping)
   Attributes: host_list="10.66.4.4 10.66.4.5 10.66.4.11 10.66.4.252 10.66.4.253 10.66.4.254" multiplier=1000 dampen=5s
   Operations: monitor interval=1s (p_ping-monitor-interval-1s)
 Group: PBX_IP
  Resource: ClusPBXIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
   Attributes: ip=10.66.6.200 nic=bond0.2 cidr_netmask=24
   Operations: monitor interval=30s (ClusPBXIP-monitor-interval-30s)
  Resource: ClusNetIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
   Attributes: ip=10.66.5.203 nic=bond0.3 cidr_netmask=24
   Operations: monitor interval=30s (ClusNetIP-monitor-interval-30s)
  Resource: ClusPBXIP-R (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Route)
```

I want to change the host list with another IPs.Any idea which is the best and safe way to do it?I'm i right that i must change in cib.xml not in any other place? 10x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're definitely correct in saying you don't want to edit the `cib.xml` directly.

Since you're using `pcs` to manage your cluster configuration, you should do it like this:

Dump the current cib to a file:

```
# pcs cluster cib cib-to-fix.txt
```

Open the file in whatever editor you like and make the appropriate changes to the `host_list` parameter:

```
# vi ./cib-to-fix.txt
```

Once you're happy with your changes, validate and push them back into the cluster:

```
# pcs cluster verify cib-to-fix.txt
# pcs cluster cib-push cib-to-fix.txt
```

If you get any errors running the verify, then you've introduced a syntax error in the cib, and should fix and re-verify before pushing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Shame on me but +1 for `verify`. Thanks)

Comment: @brownian What is the meaning of **but +1 for** ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara probably i should write "however" instead of "but". Not sure thought.